# Group acting properly discontinuous but not cocompactly on a metric space

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, geodesic, finitely-generated, geometric-group-theory

> Let $\Gamma$ act properly discontinuous but not cocompactly on a metric geodesic space $(X,d)$ by isometries s.t every closed ball in $X$ is compact. For every $x_0\in X, r\in\Bbb{R}$, define $D(x_0,r)=\{x\in X|\exists \gamma\in\Gamma$ s.t $d(x,\gamma x_0)<r\}=\bigcup_{\gamma\in\Gamma}\gamma B_r(x_0)$. Prove that $\Gamma$ is finitely generated iff for every $x_0\in X$ there exists $r\in\Bbb{R}$ s.t $D(x_0,r)$ is connected.

I tried writing $D(x_0,r)$ in different ways and understand when it is connected but I didn't get anywhere in both directions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your post could use some improvements. For example, your title mentions cocompactness but cocompactness does not appear in the post itself; is something missing somewhere?

Comment: @LeeMosher Title says not cocompactly that's why I didn't say anything about it in the post. Edited though.

Comment: Keep in mind, the entire question should always be in the post itself. The title is a brief summary and should never contain information not already in the post.

Comment: @LeeMosher Noted.

Comment: More importantly: please [provide more context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). In particular one should avoid ["I didn't get anywhere" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @LeeMosher Usually I would agree, but the fact is that I've made no progress in this question. Only thing I know is that maybe I should get some inspiration from the Milnor-Svarc lemma

Comment: The assumption "not cocompact" is weird because we can "force" it by enlarging $X$. I think you just want to emphasize the action is not assumed to be cocompact.

Comment: (English remark: one writes "$G$ acts properly discontinuous**ly**". And by the way, the word "discontinuous(ly)" is superfluous and somewhat obsolete: you just assume that the group acts properly.)

Comment: @YCor yes we don’t assume it to be cocompact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition you expressed in your comment is spot on: you can do this by imitating certain steps from the proof of the Milnor-Svarc lemma.

To start, assume $D(x_0,r)$ is connected. Consider the corresponding union of *closed* balls
$$\overline D(x_0,r) = \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \gamma \cdot \bar B_r(x_0)
$$
Using proper discontinuity, the set of those $\gamma$ for which $\bar B_r(x_0) \cap \gamma \cdot \bar B_r(x_0) \ne \emptyset$ is finite; let that set be $S$. This finite set $S$ generates the group $\Gamma$. To see why, pick any $\gamma \in \Gamma$. Using connectivity of $\bar D(x_0,r)$ there exists a sequence $\text{Id}=\delta_0,\delta_1,\ldots,\delta_M = \gamma \in \Gamma$ such that $\delta_{k-1} \cdot \bar B_r(x_0) \cap \delta_k \cdot \bar B_r(x_0) \ne \emptyset$. It follows that $\delta_{k-1}^{-1} \delta_k \in S$ for all $k$, and we have
$$\gamma = (\delta_0^{-1} \delta_1) (\delta_1^{-1}\delta_2) \cdots (\delta_{K-1}^{-1} \delta_k)
$$

For the other direction, pick a finite generating set $S \subset \Gamma$ and map the Cayley graph $C(\Gamma;S)$ to $X$ by a $\Gamma$-equivariant continuous function: the base point $p \in C(\Gamma;S)$ goes to $x_0$; every other vertex $\delta \cdot p$ goes to $\delta \cdot x_0$; and for each generator $\gamma \in S$ and each $\delta \in \Gamma$ the edge $\overline{\delta p, \delta\gamma p}$ goes to a geodesic $\overline{\delta \cdot x_0, \delta \gamma \cdot x_0}$. For each $\gamma \in S$, as $\delta \in \Gamma$ varies the length is independent of $\delta$. These lengths are therefore represented by the lengths of the finite set of geodesics $\overline{x_0, \gamma \cdot x_0}$ for $\gamma \in S$, so the lengths are strictly bounded above by some number $r$. Now verify, using that value of $r$, that the set $D(x_0,r)$ is connected: the Cayley graph is connected; its continuous image in $X$ is therefore connected, and is clearly a subset of $D(x_0,r)$; and each individual metric ball $D(x_0,r)$ is connected and contains a point of the Cayley graph.